# Visual Studio 2012 - C# - Location and size of PictureBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, picturebox

I have an issue on something I expected to be trivial.

I am developing a Visual Studio 2012 Windows Form Project using C#. In my Form there is a PictureBox `pbMaps` that I use to display stuff. I also have a checkBox `cbLab` that I use to determine between two states of the application.
One of the differences between the two states is that `pbMaps` has two be in a different Location and have a different size. So I went in the Designer of Visual Studio and checked, by moving and resizing by hand, the values I wanted for `pbMaps.Size` and `pbMaps.Location` in both states. Then I plugged those values in the code reported here:

```
    private void cbLab_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!cbLab.Checked)
        {
            pbMaps.Height = 1160;
            pbMaps.Width = 916;
            pbMaps.Location = new Point(83, 12);
        }
        else
        {
            pbMaps.Height = 580;
            pbMaps.Width = 458;
            pbMaps.Location = new Point(277, 12);
        }
    }
```

I was expecting this to work perfectly, but what I found out is that the positions during the operation of the application, the PictureBox moves to different positions that those I expected, and has different size.
The Locations are moved to the right, with respect to the ones I found in the Designer. The larger size (916 by 1160) is correct, while the other appears larger than in the Designer.

Am I forgetting something somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: autosizing and or anchors at a guess

Comment: Do you mean something in the SizeMode Property? It is currently set to Zoom.
I left anchor at its default (Top, Left)

Comment: Aye, thats the fella, also any resize events or 'docking' inside a container. note your top and left are in the correct container aren't they?

Comment: As far as i know, the container should be the form. Also, I was going through the code generated by Visual Studio, in the part where it creates the controls. The Location for `pbMaps` is set to (83, 12), but when I do that same thing in my code the Picture Box is moved to a different position.